# Why is TypeORM convinced that my model is an entity?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Working on nest.js with TypeORM/Postgres.

I've got a `calculated_properties` column on an entity, like so:

parent.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Parent {
  ...

  @Column('jsonb')
  calculated_properties: CalculatedProperties;
}
```

calculated_properties.entity.ts

```
export class CalculatedProperties {
  SomeCalc: number,

  Other Calc: number,

  NestedCalcs: NestedCalc,
```

With nestedCalc being some other similar types to calculated_properties.entity.ts.

The problem is, when I try to run the app, I get the following error message:

```
Entity "CalculatedProperties" does not have a primary column. Primary column is required to have in all your entities. Use @PrimaryColumn decorator to add a primary column to your entity.
```

But I've nowhere said this child type is an entity, and I don't want it to have a PrimaryColumn. In fact, setting an `@PrimaryColumn()` on it still shows the error - am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: use `interface`

Comment: Show your module please